# Angular module is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following context of code. **But for some reason it is returning an error** that `myApp` is not defined, when I've defined it initially and am trying to use it in multiple situations with the `mod` variable.

What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/wL54j8g9/3/

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

var mod = angular.module('myApp');

mod.directive('myList', myDirective);
mod.directive('myObject', myObject);

function myDirective(){
    var opt = {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<ul><li>This is One</li><li>This is Two</li></ul>'
  };
  return opt;
}

function myObject(){
    var opt = {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<p>A Bouncing Before Park Me Bird Joe You\'re She Tell Toenails Mix Gox I Matter TV Battered You\'ll Vim Didn\'t Oh Snapped Silly</p>'
  };
  return opt;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
var mod = angular.module('myApp');
```

should just be

```
var mod = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

(Hm. Actually, after some experimentation, I see that that does still work the way you had it, provided you inject Angular correctly... a bit redundant though, I'd still suggest combining them.)

More significantly, in your fiddle, you were injecting Angular "onLoad" -- if you change that to "nowrap in `<head>`" it will work; see https://jsfiddle.net/rtrb8ngp/.   The DOM element with `ng-app` needs to already exist when you instantiate your angular module (or else you need to use the [bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) methods to init it.)

Comment: Thanks! Forgot the loading order. I'm actually following their documentation, when doing that: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp

Comment: Their documentation appears to suggest the same single-line method I did. (The 2nd "without the dependencies array" call is just another way to retrieve an already-instantiated module if the variable it was originally set on is unavailable for whatever reason)